# Discord.js v13 embed is empty when sent to a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I want to send an embed to a channel it just sends an empty message.

Image:

[image]

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setDescription("Description");

console.log(embed);
return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Comment: It seems that you may be suppressing the embeds. Do you have a bot suppressing them, or is someone else doing it?

Comment: In the channel where i do the testing its only me and the Bot and the Bot has all of the Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    embed.setTitle("Title")
    embed.setDescription("Description");

console.log(embed);
return message.channel.send(embed);
```

Try this out heres my discord otherwise NullTopdog#9865

Comment: Since im using v13 of Discord.js i have to send the Embed like this:
`channel.send({ embeds: [embed, embed2] });`

Comment: Downvoted as OP clearly states in their question that they're using discord.js v13 and this answer won't work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake.

I had "*Link preview*" turned off in my user settings on Discord.